# Como usar duas classes navbar-right na mesma página?

Tags: menu

Estou criando um layout para um sistema em ASP que trabalha com o conceito de content onde preciso usar duas barras de navegação, uma embaixo da outra. Seria 'Menu principal e Menu 2.

A questão é que preciso usar a classe="navbar-right" nos dois, para que gere o ícone do sanduíche e liste os itens do menu no mobile, mas quando aciono o ícone do  menu2 ele abre a lista do menu principal.

Se eu remover o Menu Principal o Menu2 funciona, ou seja, os dois estão funcionando perfeitamente. Acho que um esta conflitando com o outro.

Segue código, Menu Principal que fica no site.master.aspx

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="menuprincipal">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="background-color: #143b78">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header" style="background-color: #143b78" ;>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="background-color: #143b78" ;><img src="../img/cliente.png" class="logocliente img-responsive" /></a>
        <div class="title" style="width: 500px; padding-top:4%;padding-left:40%" ;>
            <h5 class="navbar-text">Teste de menu</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="../navbar/" style="color:#fff;">Fale com o </br> </a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/" style="color:#fff;">Cronômetro</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Código menu2 que fica na página que herda o menu principal do site.master:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu2">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Início</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Chapas</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">Comprovante</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando o mesmo `ID` nos dois navbars. Basta trocar essas duas linhas.

```
data-target="#navbar2"
```

e mudar o respequitivo ID

```
<div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Segue abaixo um exemplo

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="menuprincipal">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="background-color: #143b78">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header" style="background-color: #143b78" ;>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="background-color: #143b78" ;><img src="../img/cliente.png" class="logocliente img-responsive" /></a>
        <div class="title" style="width: 500px; padding-top:4%;padding-left:40%" ;>
            <h5 class="navbar-text">Teste menu</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="../navbar/" style="color:#fff;">Fale com o </br> </a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/" style="color:#fff;">Cronômetro</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container -->
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="menu2">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Início</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Chapas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Comprovante</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Phelipe, arrasou !!! Deu certo, nunca havia usado dois menus em uma mesma página. Muito obrigada!!

Comment: Que bom, considere finalizar a pergunta então.

Comment: Não estou sabendo encerrar a pergunta como resolvida.

Comment: Vá na resposta que você considera certa e do lado esquerdo da pergunta vai aparecer um botão de "check". Só clicar nesse botão